# Azure data studio will not bulk insert in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: azure

I am using the newest version of Azure Data Studio on Mac. I am not able to bulk insert in UTF-8 encoding

I have tried bulk inserting UTF-8 encoded CSV file into a table. I have specified all columns as Varchar datatype, which is UTF-8 compatible. I also changed the collation of the table to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8. Unfortunately, I am still getting bad results as you can see in the screenshot. Also, I cannot specify what encoding I want in the importing due to my system OS.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck1Vw.png)